# using javascript to control CSS3 animation pause and running

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to use pure javascript to create a CSS3 animation, it works. And then I want make this animation can pause when mouse enter the container,and running when mouse leave the container. I use `animate.pause`,`animate.play`& `animationPlayState`,but it still doesn't work. So,how to make it works? Sorry my English, Thank you very much!

---

**Here is my code:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var ulNode = document.querySelector(".container>ul"),
  frames = [
   {left: 0},
   {left: '-700px'},
   {left: 0}
  ],
  timing = {
   duration: 10000,
   iterations: Infinity,
  };
 ulNode.animate(frames, timing);
 var player = ulNode.animate(frames);

 ulNode.onmouseover = function(){
  // player.pause();
  this.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
 }
 ulNode.onmouseout = function(){
  // player.play();
  this.style.animationPlayState = "running";
 }
}
```

```css
body,ul{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul{list-style-type: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 1200px;}
ul>li{width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;}
ul>li:nth-child(odd){background-color: red;}
ul>li:nth-child(even){background-color: green;}
/*@keyframes doMove{
 form{left: 0;}
 50%{left: -700px;}
 to{left: 0px;}
}
ul{animation: doMove 20s linear infinite;}
.container:hover ul{animation-play-state:paused;}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS3 Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently for Chrome, Safari and Opera the correct js syntax to pause an animation is

```
 document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
```

(note the webkit at the beginning). This is according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationplaystate.asp), however despite a couple of attempts i was unable to get it working. (see below)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ulNode = document.querySelector("#container"),
 frames = [
  {left: '0px'},
  {left: '-700px'},
  {left: '-100%'}
 ],
 timing = {
  duration: 10000,
  iterations: Infinity,
 };
  ulNode.animate(frames, timing);
 
  ulNode.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
  }
  ulNode.onmouseout = function() {
     document.getElementById("container").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
};
```

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1200px;
}
ul>li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
ul>li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
ul>li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS3 Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so kind of you. yes, i also think `WebkitAnimationPlayState` is correct syntax, but it doesn't work. Maybe has other reason or unsupported.

Comment: yes, it's unfortunate, i tried it with and without initialising it in css, but to no avail :(

Comment: `Webkit` or `webkit` with lowercase first letter?

Comment: Uppercase @Qwertiy